# Fedora Core yum update keeps hanging

Tags: fedora, yum

When I run `yum update` it hangs at the end with no error message.

If I run `sudo yum install httpd` it hangs with no error.

I read that using `strace` should give more info, but when I try that it says `no such command strace`.

I have `fedora` core running on VirtualBox, `Win 7` is the host computer, just trying to install `apache / php / mysql` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check network connection from virtual machine to the Internet and DNS settings. Possibly `yum` is unable to connect repo servers.

`strace` is a separate package. You can install it after yum issue will be resolved.